# SoX - Sound eXchange for java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, detection, sox

Someone knows if Sox has allready library for java? like a wrapper or binding ?

Sox has a really good function to record audio and detect when someone is speaking with its silence parameter and I want to use it in java.

I know that you can use the command line to call sox and read the output, but I think it is not a good practice to do such thing.

maybe a solution with jni?

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I have developed recently a simple wrapper around sox. You can find the project on GitHub. See, maybe it will help.
[Sox wrapper written in java, available on Github](https://github.com/corballis/sox-wrapper-java)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11480990)

Comment: Sorry mjp66,
How could my Answer make better to avoid the -1 vote? The questioner was looking for a library and i tought a link will be a perfect answer for it and self explanatory, but i do not really know, what other text i could put around the link. Pls, help to make my answer better.